Laravel Bassets (Backpack) with nginx in Docker
I have 3 containers: nginx + php fpm + mysql.
The php application uses Laravel Backpack, which downloads the necessary resources via Basset.
The problem is that it uses base_path() to search for resources, not suspecting that they are not "nearby". Such a request is being generated:
enter image description here
And maybe it would work if http://localhost:80 it was not processed by nginx, which cannot find such a resource. What is the right way to solve this situation? Thank you in advance. Nginx Configuration:
enter image description here
Before I realized that this was the problem, I was experimenting with symlinks

Code excerpts and error-messages are best pasted into the question, rather than shown as screen-dumps. That way, they're easier for people to read and easier to find when searching. Please edit the question to replace the images with text, delimited by triple-back-ticks.

For anyone facing the same issue, @jsssy provided the solution in: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/5526
It was a ngix configuration problem.
